# Origin of chaos in Chua's circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems

I am doing a project on [Chua's circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chua%27s_circuit), but I can't seem to find anything that explains where the chaotic nature of the system comes from. Does anyone know of articles that explain it well on an undergraduate level, or themselves know of why this particular circuit is chaotic?

Comment: Circuit diagram, please.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone is going to be able to give you an answer as to where the chaotic behaviour _comes from_, other than that it is a non-linear dynamical system that exhibits the typical signs of chaos, i.e. deterministic but complex behaviour that displays sensitive dependence on initial conditions.  There's some interesting information in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chua%27s_circuit)

Comment: Look for "A chaotic attractor from Chua's circuit" by T. Matsumoto (1984): he discusses the chaos in a simpler version of the original Chua's circuit (the circuit diagram of the specific circuit is reported).